# Body Field Trimming

Tags: nodes, entities

Does anyone have a solution to the following issue?

I have a body field that I would like to have initially trimmed with a "Read more" link to expand the remainder of the text. This is specifically only on the Node page (so not a views issue) of a custom content type.

I have tried the Smart Trim module, but it doesn't expand the text when click, it just links back to the node page, which is what I'd expect from a views to node link.

Does anyone have any other ideas? I'm stuck currently, either I leave it consistently expanded or just have it trimmed with no "read more" link. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you need the [Expand Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/expanding_formatter) module. From the project page:

> This module provides a formatter for existing text, long text and text with summary widget types. This module allows you to change how the content is being display (formatted) by providing new format types:
>   **Trimmed (expandable)**
>   **Summary or Trimmed (expandable)**

Granted, this is only for D7, but you didn't tag your question with core version, so I'm guessing that you're using D7.